# Check if a value is present in a content - Struts2

Tags: jsp, struts2, struts1

How can I check if a value is present in a table in Struts2?
This is how it works in Struts1.

```
  <logic:present name="<%=Globals.ERROR_KEY%>">
        <table class="table">
          <tr>
            <td class="name" color="red">
    </logic:present>
              <html:errors />
    <logic:present name="<%=Globals.ERROR_KEY%>">
         </td>
      </tr>
     </table>
</logic:present>
```

Comment: Ariana, it would be really a lot simpler and straight for you to stop and spend a couple of days reading the Struts2 documentation. Asking every single bit of informations, and then copy-paste them without fully understand them is not a good way to go. BTW what you want is the `<s:if>` tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a method [`hasActionErrors()`](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/interceptor/ValidationAware.html#hasActionErrors--) of `ActionSupport` class that could be checked in JSP if you need to wrap some content around [`<s:actionerror/>`](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/actionerror-tag.html). You action should extend that class.

> Render action errors if they exists the specific layout of the rendering depends on the theme itself. Empty (null or blank string) errors will not be printed. The action error strings will be html escaped by default.

---

`<logic:present>` equivalent in Struts2 is

```xml
<s:if test="somekey != null && somekey != ''">
```

---

where `somekey` is a variable in the valueStack, that has `action` scope. AFAIK the `logic:present` tag searching in all scopes, so you can add `#attr` prefix to the key.